# `strdup` re-implementation in assembly

Tags: beginner, stack, assembly, nasm, amd64

I am posting a message here because I am new to assembly programming. My goal today was to re-code `strdup` in assembly, so to save my first parameter which is a string (`const char*`), I have doubts when handling RSP to reserve space for the string and how I reset it at the end.

However I'm not sure I did well, and I would like to have a review, and advice on what I could improve.

```
extern malloc extern _ft_strlen extern _ft_strcpy



section .text
    global  _ft_strdup

    _ft_strdup:
            push        rbp                   ; prologue                      
            mov         rbp, rsp              ; prologue           
            sub         rsp, 8                ; reserve space for string                   
            mov         qword [rbp - 8], rdi  ; put first param on the stack
            call         _ft_strlen           ; strlen the first param
            mov         rdi, rax              ; put return value on the rdi register                       
            call        malloc                ; malloc rdi bytes                        
            cmp         rax, 0                ; check if malloc failed                                
            je          return                               
            mov         rdi, rax              ; put malloc address in rdi  (DEST)                            
            mov         rsi, qword [rbp - 8]  ; put source address in rsi (SRC)
            call        _ft_strcpy            ; copy                 
            add         rsp, 8                ; reset                     
            pop         rbp                   ; epilogue                             
            ret
    
    return:
            xor         rax, rax
            add         rsp, 8                   
            pop         rbp                                     
            ret
```

Comment: Welcome to code review! Do you know if the code works as expected?

Comment: To be a little blunt, this looks a lot like you added some comments to code generated by a compiler. You repeatedly describe the instruction `sub rsp, 8` as “reserve space for string” when, in fact, its purpose is to maintain the required 16-bit alignment of the stack pointer in the System V ABI. The string is stored on the heap, and it is *never* safe to return a pointer to data on the current stack frame. No one who knew to subtract eight bytes after pushing eight bytes would think that `malloc` stored the string in them.

Comment: You also use the internal names from one implementation of the C standard library, when any human writing from scratch would use the documented, human-readable names.

Comment: By the way, your compiler will generate better code if you tell it to omit the frame pointer and optimize for space. You could replace the lines with `rbp` with a `push rdi`.

Answer (score 2):

If you’re writing x86_64 code, you should be following [the System V x86_64 ABI.](https://gitlab.com/x86-psABIs/x86-64-ABI/-/jobs/artifacts/master/raw/x86-64-ABI/abi.pdf?job=build)  I’m not sure where your `_ft_` versions of the system calls are coming from, but you should be able to call `strlen`, `malloc` and other standard-library functions with the arguments in registers, not using the stack except to save variables.  (You appear to be doing this correctly.)

You need to reserve space for the terminating null byte, which is not counted in the length reported by `strlen`.  You also need to set this in the duplicate.  Currently, you could return an unterminated string!

Since you already check the exact length of the string before you duplicate it, you are better off calling `memcpy`, which should be more optimized than `strcpy`.  And is definitely safer from buffer overruns!

If you picked this exercise on your own, you should know to avoid the old-fashioned C library functions that don’t bounds-check the string.  For new code, you always want a function like this to take an upper bound on the length (which could be `SIZE_MAX`).  This very code contains a bug which could cause an unterminated string to generate a buffer overrun!

You can save a few bytes by having the check to see if allocation failed jump over the code to copy, and writing the epilogue only once.

There is no reason for you to set up `rbp` as a frame pointer.  The fact that you mislabel what these lines do is going to make your grader realize that you copied them from code generated by a compiler.

You’re pretty much stuck calling `malloc`, but you can replace the calls to `strlen` and `strcpy` with x86 string instructions (`scasb` and `movsb`), and in an exercise like this, you should.

Comment: Basically, I didn't use the prologue/epilogue because saving the value of my chain on my stack could simply be done with push.

However I have noticed that compilers define a stack frame when I manually manipulate the stack to define local variables. Therefore in my case I did this for learning interests and would like to save the source string by manipulating the stack while respecting the 16 byte alignment.
could you tell me how to achieve this correctly ?

PS: The strlen etc functions are perfect copies of the glibc functions

Comment: @pharaoh2000 To maintain the 16-byte alignment of the stack pointer, if you push an odd number of 8-byte registers onto the stack, subtract another eight bytes from `rsp`.